# Spring rabbit and JDBC transaction issue

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have two spring rabbit consumers A and B.

consumer A:

```
protected void process(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {
   Session mysession=sessionRepository.findOne(5);
   mysession.setMyField("bla");
   sessionRepository.save(mysession);
   ServicesHelper.convertAndSend(<Consumer B token>, mysession.getId());

}
```

Consumer B:

```
protected void process(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {
   //getting event from message
   Long sessionId=5;
   Session mysession=sessionRepository.findOne(sessionId);
   mysession.setMyField("bla-bla");
   //And I get there unpredictable optimistic locking exception. 
   sessionRepository.save(mysession);


}
```

It seems like jdbc transaction in consumer A is being committed after exit from listener method, that's why overlapping is possible. My 'session' entiry has a @Version column, that;s why I discovered this issue. How to avoid it and is it good approach to do this? I just need to process a session in consumer A and then pass to consumer B.

Comment: Just quickly, you're saying that the transaction only completes after the method exits or after the `save` completes ? The latter would only be possible if you explicitly are annotating the caller of `process` with `@Transactional`. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi, yes, I marked onMessage methods as @Transactional, and process is running inside it. So The issue is I randomly get  OptimisticException while saving entities in A or 2. I moved all this logic to separate class that marked with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). Is it a good way?

Comment: Ok, definitely important information for the question. I think you just need to clean up the transactional blocks. Take them off and try as i've suggested in the answer and I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be talking about `spring-data` here not `spring-jdbc`. If this is the case ( apologies if it's not ) and you are using `CrudRepository` then it's probably because interactions with the repository are all `@Transactional`.

For example, here is the actual signature of save

```
@Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

I would suggest refactoring to the following and trying again :-

```
protected void process(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {

   ServicesHelper.convertAndSend(<Consumer B token>,adaptSession().getId()));

}

@Transactional
protected Session adaptSession(){
   Session mysession=sessionRepository.findOne(5);
   mysession.setMyField("bla");
   sessionRepository.save(mysession);
   return mysession; 
}
```

and

```
@Transactional
protected void process(Message amqpMessage, Channel channel)
            throws Exception {
   //getting event from message
   Long sessionId=5;
   Session mysession=sessionRepository.findOne(sessionId);
   mysession.setMyField("bla-bla");
   //And I get there unpredictable optimistic locking exception. 
   sessionRepository.save(mysession);
}
```

Which should make the transactional units match up. Try that and me know.